# Type without body in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having problems tracking an array initialized to an empty Type (table of varchar2) object. It's inside a loop and outputs indexes from what I think is coming from the database. I've done my research with the "as table of varchar2" and I think it just simply means a column of a table with varchar as a type.

From what I understood, the "invArry" declared as the type "item_val" in the "item_inv" header just basically means invArry is a varchar, since item_val is a varchar right? But I got confused when in the item_inv body, the invArry is initialized to item_val again. Was it initialized to a varchar again? Or does         the type item_val already pointing out to a column in the database? If it's the latter, I'm not sure how it got pointed to the database.

```
    create or replace TYPE "item_inv" AS OBJECT
    (invArry item_val,    --invArry declared as item_val
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION item_inv
             RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION item_inv( recrd VARCHAR2 )
             RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    ) FINAL;
```

=========

```
    create or replace TYPE BODY "item_inv" AS

    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION item_inv
             RETURN SELF AS RESULT
       IS
       BEGIN
          invArry := item_val    --invArry initialized to item_val. Whut
          RETURN;
       END;
```

=========

```
    create or replace TYPE "item_val" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2( 240 );
    --item_val object, does this points already to the database or just an empty object
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `item_val` as [a nested table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjcol.htm) collection.

In your object type `invArry` is of that type, so it is a nested table - that is, an unordered collection of strings, each of which is up to 240 characters.

In your object type body you're initialising the `invArry` to an empty collection:

```
invArry := item_val();
```

It is not initialised to a varchar, it's initialised to an empty nested table of varchars. It isn't pointing to any data, table or column in the database. It's a collection which has no elements in it. You can now write code to add elements to that collection. The values could come from elsewhere in the database but there is no automatic link.